# Unable to change the Theme of Splash screen in my application?

Tags: android, styles, splash-screen

In my application, user can change the theme of an application from setting inside the application. It working in all other screen inside the application. But it is not working for splash screen only. When user change the theme of an application then I load one Class which has only functionality to call Splash screen.

Till now I have:-

```
public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity {

Preferences pref;
MediaPlayer mySong;
int maxVolume = 100;

Constant constant;
SharedPreferences app_preferences;
int appTheme;
int themeColor;
int appColor;
LinearLayout relative_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
   // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   // getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
     //       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



    app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    appColor = app_preferences.getInt("color", 0);
    appTheme = app_preferences.getInt("theme", 0);
    System.out.println("adweff"+appColor+"dfdscsbv"+appTheme);

    themeColor = appColor;
    constant.color = appColor;


    if (themeColor == 0){
        setTheme(Constant.theme);
    }else if (appTheme == 0){
        setTheme(Constant.theme);
    }else{
        setTheme(appTheme);
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    relative_layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
  /*  if (appColor==(-16537100)){

        System.out.println("called=="+Constant.color);


        relative_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5ecbf4"));
    }*/

    if (appColor != 0) {

        if (appColor == -16537100) {
            relative_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0f95dc"));
        } else {

            relative_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);


        }


      //  relative_layout.setBackgroundColor(Constant.color);

    }




    SharedPreferences prefss = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor edts = prefss.edit();
    edts.putString("extra", "Yes");
    edts.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MyAlarmService.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);


    //  mySong.start();

    pref = new Preferences(ActivitySplash.this);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (appColor != 0) {

                if (appColor == -16537100) {
                    relative_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0f95dc"));
                } else {

                    relative_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);


                }


                //relative_layout.setBackgroundColor(Constant.color);

            }

            if (pref.getStringPreference(ActivitySplash.this, "login").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, ActivityHome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, ActivityLoginRegistration.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //   mySong.release();
                finish();

            }


        }
    }, 3 * 1000); // wait for 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Have you got right value on themeColor or constant.color?

Comment: @Haresh yes i have the right theame color .

Comment: After change theme have you restart splash activity?

Comment: sorry @Haresh ..  have solved the issue..actually the splash  screen is full image..and by mistake i try to change the color that's why.

Comment: Ok, glad to help you.